# What is the difference between: "being+adjective" and "being+past participle"?

Tags: passive-voice, gerunds, past-participles

I've been told that **being+past participle** is tenseless.

Even if it's tenseless, there must be some rules for it too. Does it convey the reason for an action, or does it mean that one action is followed by another?

1. Being helped by Ram, I did my homework.
   (Meaning: I was helped by Ram and I did my homework. Or, because I was helped by Ram, I did my homework. Which meaning does it convey?)

I have also been told that **being+adjective** is used to show the reason for the action in the main clause.

2. Being employed in teachings at a school, I hardly managed time for painting.
   (does it show the 'reason'?)

Does "being+past participle" also show the reason?

Being + past participle ---> Being + helped/employed

Comment: Related: **1.** [Being taken and being beaten](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106638/being-taken-and-being-beaten) **2.** [Being+past participle as a gerund](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105232/beingpast-participle-as-a-gerund) **3.** [“Being surrounded” or have been surrounded?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106882/being-surrounded-or-have-been-surrounded)

Comment: TRomano's a good answer. You should study it carefully and learn from it. Then, you should accept it :)

Answer (score 4):

The present participle plus past participle is understood to supply the reason or basis for the action in the matrix clause. The combination of participles expresses a fact and the fact is understood to be pertinent to the action taken, or to the situation undergone, by the subject of the independent clause.

> **Being stressed** by the idiocy of her obstructionist coworkers, she took a much-needed vacation.
>
> **Feeling stressed** by the idiocy of her obstructionist coworkers, she took a much-needed vacation.
>
> She got a blister on her heel, **having walked** too far in her new shoes.
>
> **Having heard** that the quarterly meeting in London had been postponed, she phoned the airline to change her flight.

With an adjective in place of the past participle, the dependent clause expresses a state that applies to the subject at the time of the action or situation given in the independent clause. With **being** or **feeling**, it too may be understood as the reason or basis of that action or situation.

> **Feeling blue**, she sang a sad song.
>
> **Being tall**, she joined the volleyball team.